# Discord.JS - Moving users in Discord to your VC using roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to move all users from a VC with a specific role, for example: **!summon @role**

With that, all users with that specific role should come to the VC where the user typed that command

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
else if (command === 'summon') {
                    const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
                    message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                        member.voice.setChannel(channel);
                    });
                    message.channel.send(`${message.author} users moved to your channel!`);
                }
```

At the moment i'm moving all users, however I only want users with the informed role

I tried to use:

```
                    message.mentions.roles.forEach(member => {
                        member.setChannel(channel);
                    });
```

But without success... can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    member.voice.setChannel(channel);
});
```

with

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    if(member.roles.cache.has(message.mentions.roles.first()) {
        member.voice.setChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Since member.roles.cache is a `Collection` it has a function `.has`. We take the first role mention from the message using `message.mentions.roles.first()` and check if it exists in the user's current roles using `member.roles.cache.has()`. If the user does have the first role mentioned in the message, the function returns `true` and we can move the to the specified channel. Hope this helps, don't forget about https://discord.js.org/#/docs for some documentation, can be quite useful .